# Polarion: Set default approver for workitems

Tags: polarion

I need to set a default person to approve the workitems in my project (e.g. when a new defect is created, the default approver should be automatically added). I know that templates exist, my problem with using templates is, that I have to fill the "required" fields, which I'd like to keep empty on creation of the workitem.

Is there a way to either add a default approver without using templates or keep "required" fields empty when creating workitem templates?

Every answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This has been answered by Alexey Andrianov on the [Siemens Polarion Forum](https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/feed/0D54O00007ZTbSfSAL).*

---

You can add the default approvers to workitems by editing the **workflow script** (for initial status).

For this to work you have to add the "**AddDefaultApprovals**" function and the parameter "**approvals.roles**" with your default approver role as the parameter value. Alternatively you can add specific users as approvers by using the "**approvals.users**" parameter.